# Is picking up fixed pixel rgb values from a camera pic using arduino/uC possible?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, camera

Does arduino have enough processing power to pick up say 20 pixel rgb values from a small single image and find the average value?Can we do it with any other microcontroller?Are any code snippets available?

Comment: Question is vauge. If you are taking a single image, the processing power is adequate. The camera interface is not clear. If USB, you need to find a uC with USB host, several available. If not USB but parallel interface, you cannot do this with simple CPU, you need something more comprehensive. STM32 etc.

Comment: Yes I am taking a single image. I am going to use something like CMOS Camera - 640x480 TCM8230MD, not yet decided.Actually all I need is to pick up rgb values from a paper placed 1cm from the camera and reading an area of 15mm2. I am not going to use a digital camera so I cant use the usb.So how can I go about this? Thanking you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a microcontroller and this camera ( https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8667 ) to do what you want. You would have the microcontroller send some configuration and then the "take picture" command to the camera, then read the pixel data from the parallel data outputs. Most uCs don't have enough memory to store a whole photo, so you'd have to handle the pixels you want as they come in and discard the rest.

Comment: Or also can use a microSD card as a storage buffer

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Arduino guy. From a hardware perspective, if you can connect the µC to the camera (i.e. with the right interface), there is no reason why you cannot do what you want.

If you choose to use STM32, you can use a version that has a camera interface and you can accomplish this pretty easily.